# Protobuf issue (alexeyxo/protobuf-swift)

Tags: java, ios, swift, xcode7, protocol-buffers

I recieved a project where Java .proto files were converted into Swift 1.0. Now I am going to get the same but in Swift 2.0. I have read instructions about How To Install Protobuf Compiler (https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-swift) but they seem to me not clear, that is why I have a few questions:

1. Why do they ask to `Add ./src/ProtocolBuffers/ProtocolBuffers.xcodeproj in your project`?
2. They are asking in "Compile ".proto" files." to use command `protoc  person.proto --swift_out="./"` and it is not enough. I am having several .proto files that depend on each other and when I try to run this command for a single .proto file I get the following:

   ruslans-imac:Desktop ruslan$ protoc  commands.proto --swift_out="./"
   MobileStartup.proto: File not found.
   TaskListPortion.proto: File not found.
   commands.proto: Import "MobileStartup.proto" was not found or had errors.
   commands.proto: Import "TaskListPortion.proto" was not found or had errors.
   commands.proto:225:14: "ContainerType" is not defined.
   commands.proto:226:14: "FocusEnum" is not defined.
   commands.proto:230:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:231:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:254:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:279:14: "LinkTypeEnum" is not defined.
   commands.proto:297:14: "FocusEnum" is not defined.
   commands.proto:312:14: "OffsetDateTimeMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:317:14: "FocusEnum" is not defined.
   commands.proto:318:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:322:14: "FocusEnum" is not defined.
   commands.proto:324:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:344:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:348:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.
   commands.proto:352:14: "OffsetDateMessage" is not defined.

I think that there should exist some way to group the files and compile them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to alexeyxo/protobuf-swift, please, note that it is built on the basis of Protocol Buffers from Google, so read google's article about how to use it and you will find what you are looking for.